# pyst3 не совершает звонок

Tags: python, python-3.x, asterisk

Всем добрый день. 
Решила просто написать скрипт, чтобы позвонить со своего номера мультифон на свой мобильный.

Но не получается.
С pyst3 очень плохо разобралась.

Подскажите пожалуйста, как подправить код, чтобы я смогла позвонить?

```
import asterisk
from asterisk import manager

manager_manager = asterisk.manager.Manager()
manager = manager_manager
try:
    try:
        manager.connect('localhost') # Подключение к Астериску, указываю хост
        manager.login('yana','passwd') # Указываю пользователя и пароль из manager.conf
        call_for_numbers = manager.originate(channel='SIP/79210335510@multifon',exten= '7906*******',context='outcoling',priority='1')
        print (call_for_numbers)
    except:print('Problems')
except: print('Big Problem!')
finally:
    manager.close()
```

Выдает мне первое исключение 'Problem'

Мой extensions:

```
[outcoling]
exten=>_7XXXXXXXXXX,1,Dial(SIP/multifon/${EXTEN})
```

Мой sip:

```
[multifon]
dtmfmode=inband
username=79210335510
type=friend
secret=secret
host=sbc.megafon.ru
fromuser=79210335510
fromdomain=multifon.ru
port=5060
nat=yes
context=incoming
insecure=port,invite
```

Comment: Попробуйте еще и порт указать для manager interface. И на всякий случай проверьте manager.conf

Comment: Снова выдает 'Problems'. Добавила порт  call_for_numbers = manager.originate(channel='SIP/79210335510@multifon', exten='7906*******', context='outcoling', priority='1',port = 5060) и пересмотрела manager.conf. Вроде всё правильно. Однако теперь при попытках позвонить, Asterisk периодически в CLI показывает вот такую строку "-- Registration for '79210335510@sbc.multifon.ru" timed put, trying again (Attempt #1)

Comment: Есть ли в sip.conf в секции global такая строчка: srvlookup=yes ?